# Query associated MAX column with all it's fields in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have three database tables:

- **car**

  - id
- **speed**

  - id
  - actual_speed
  - car_id
  - gear_id
- **gear**

  - id

I would like to select max speeds of all cars and the gear they achieve the max speed with. I got to the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(speed.actual_speed)
FROM car
INNER JOIN speed ON car.id = speed.car_id
GROUP BY car.id;
```

This query works but doesn't return the gear. If I include `gear_id` in the select `SELECT MAX(speed.actual_speed), speed.gear_id`. The database complains that `gear_id` should be included in group by or aggregate function.

But if I include it in the group by `GROUP BY car.id, speed.gear_id` the query returns max speeds for all gears which I'm not interested in.

Is there maybe a way to get back all cars with their max speed and the gear they achieve it in?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and portable solution uses a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from speed s
where s.actual_speed = (select max(s1.actual_speed) from speed s1 where s1.car_id = s.car_id)
```

This would benefit an index on `(car_id, actual_speed)`.

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (car_id) s.*
from speed s
order by car_id, actual_speed desc
```

Or, if you want to allow ties:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, rank() over(partition by car_id order by actual_speed desc) rn
    from speed s
) s
where rn = 1
```